# Installing sqlite3 on node in Yocto showing Error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node

Tags: node.js, sqlite, yocto

**Installing sqlite3 in node application on node application in Yocto os it allowed to install in

node v14.15.5  SQLite3 v3.22.0

But it was showing error on updated versions.

As of now the latest node and sqlite3 version is

node v15.x

sqlite v3.34

On this version it was unable to install sqlite3 in node application
package and throwing below error Though sqlite3 with v3.34.x was
installed in Yocto.

```
verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install', 'sqlite3' ]   error node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok 

error node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0 

error node-pre-gyp info using node@15.8.0 | linux | arm 

error node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 

error node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node" (not found) 

error node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm.tar.gz error node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm.tar.gz


error node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm.tar.gz error node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.2 and node@15.8.0 (node-v88 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 

error node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.2/napi-v3-linux-arm.tar.gz


error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok error gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2 

error gyp info using node@15.8.0 | linux | arm error gyp info ok 

error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok error gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2 

error gyp info using node@15.8.0 | linux | arm 

error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.5.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3" 

error gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3 error gyp info spawn args [ 

error gyp info spawn args '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py', error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp', 

error gyp info spawn args '-f', 

error gyp info spawn args 'make', error gyp info spawn args '-I', error gyp info spawn args '/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',


error gyp info spawn args '-I', error gyp info spawn args '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi', 

error gyp info spawn args '-I', 

error gyp info spawn args '/home/root/.cache/node-gyp/15.8.0/include/node/common.gypi', 

error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library', 

error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default', 

error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/root/.cache/node-gyp/15.8.0', 

error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp', 

error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/root/.cache/node-gyp/15.8.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',


error gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3', 

error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8', 

error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.', error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel', 

error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output', 

error gyp info spawn args 'build', error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.' 

error gyp info spawn args ] error gyp info ok error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok error gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2 error gyp info using node@15.8.0 | linux | arm 

error gyp info spawn make error gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ] error Traceback (most recent call last): error File "./extract.py", line 2, in <module> 

error import tarfile error ImportError: No module named tarfile error make: *** [deps/action_before_build.target.mk:13: Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3340000/sqlite3.c] Error 1 

error gyp ERR! build error error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 

error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)


error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20) 

error gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12) 

error gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.88-Agriscan-6.0.0+g9512b3d 

error gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3" 

error gyp ERR! cwd /home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3 

error gyp ERR! node -v v15.8.0 

error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2 

error gyp ERR! not ok 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build
--module=/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm/node_sqlite3.node
--module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-arm
--napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1) 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)


error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:378:20) 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16) 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5) 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.88-Agriscan-6.0.0+g9512b3d 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/root/Livestock-Recording-System/Agriscan/node_modules/sqlite3 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v15.8.0 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0 

error node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok verbose exit 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first check if gcc is available or not with this given command ***gcc --version***

If not available than install it with given command ***bitbake meta-toolchain***

After that remove node_modules by ***rm -rf node_modules***

Install ***npm*** globally

Remove ***package-lock.json*** file

Now install sqlite3 from source with this command ***npm install --build-from-source --sqlite=/usr/local/opt/sqlite/*** will allow you to install sqlite3 on Yocto.

Reference Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3